# Derivation of the Rutherford scattering formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, scattering, coulombs-law

I have been trying to look for a derivation of the [Rutherford scattering formula from Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/rutsca.html), but cannot find one. It doesn't show up in [the original paper](http://www.chemteam.info/Chem-History/Rutherford-1911/Rutherford-1911.html) How is this equation derived?

$$N(\theta) = \frac{N_i nLZ^2k^2e^4}{4r^2 KE^2\sin^4(\theta/2)}$$
where

- $N_i$ is the number of incident alpha particles
- $n$ is the number of atoms per unit volume in the target
- $L$ is the thickness of the target
- $Z$ is the atomic number of the target
- $e$ is the electron charge
- $k$ is Coulomb's constant
- $r$ is the target-to-detector distance
- $KE$ is the kinetic energy of the alpha particle
- $\theta$ is the scattering angle

Comment: Check _Modern Physics: Arthur Beiser_ chapter 4: appendix [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pyFbONhSbnsC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=arthur+beiser+modern+physics+rutherford+scattering&source=bl&ots=FOLEwlCnjq&sig=8LSKTeQZepYLrOpUZK4nGdHCJMc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibnZry87zKAhWCB44KHT8pDiQQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=arthur%20beiser%20modern%20physics%20rutherford%20scattering&f=false)

Comment: Do you need an explanation of the derivation of the formula from scratch or you got stuck during the studying of the article?

Answer (score 1):

In the Wikipedia article about rutherford scattering the derivation of the scattering cross section
$$ \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} =\left(\frac{ Z_1 Z_2 e^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 m v_0^2}\right)^2 \csc^4{\left(\frac{\Theta}{2}\right)}$$
is given. Let's rewrite that in your notation: $Z_1 = Z$, $Z_2 = 4$, $k = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}$ and $KE = \frac{1}{2}m v^2$:
$$ \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} =\left(\frac{ Z e^2 k}{KE}\right)^2 \csc^4{\left(\frac{\Theta}{2}\right)} = \frac{Z^2 k^2 e^4}{ KE^2\sin^4(\theta/2)}$$
The relation between the cross section and the number of detected particles is
$$\frac{N(\theta)}{N_i} = \frac{nL}{4r^2} \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}$$
$nL$ gives the number of targets to scatter from and $1/(4r^2)$ is because at a bigger distance the intensity goes down by this factor (I'm sure about the $r^2$ but not exactly about the factor. I thought it would be $2\pi$ so maybe I did an error there.)

I hope this helps.